# Как исправить ошибку Process finished with exit code 1 в pycharm

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, pycharm, chromedriver

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая парсит номера товаров с переходом на следующие страницы списка.

```
import re
import chromedriver_binary
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.agilent.com/en/product/biopharma-hplc-analysis/aggregate-fragment-analysis/agilent-bio-sec-5')

part_number = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'buy-prods-table').text
number_list = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d', part_number)

browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-forward").click()

print(part_number)
print(number_list)
```

[image: код страницы]

При запуске программы выдает ошибку Process finished with exit code 1. Также в терминале на скриншоте, честно говоря, разобраться сложно.

[image: сриншот с терминала]

И еще такой вопрос, почему pycharm может возвращать разные данные, при запуске одной и той же программы в один раз выдает полный список номеров, в другой раз другой пустой? Не понимаю, что с этим делать.

Answer (score 1):

`Process finished with exit code 1` происходит, если скрипт не выполнился до конца, а прервался из-за какой-либо ошибки. Поэтому в будущем копируйте текст ошибки (он на вашем скриншоте) и добавляйте его в вопрос.

В вашем случае произошла ошибка в строке `browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-forward").click()` - взаимодействие с элементом невозможно. Невозможно оно, т.к. скрипт пытается кликнуть на кнопку перехода на предыдущую страницу, а её нет, т.к. вы находитесь на первой. Я думаю, вы хотели перейти на страницу вперёд, а не назад. Вы неверно составили селектор `"page-forward"`, кнопка перехода на след. страницу находится внутри `<li>` и внутри `<a>`. Исправить это - и ошибки не будет. Но партийные номера вы так не спарсите, т.к. селектор `'buy-prods-table'` для них тоже неверный - он выбирает всю таблицу, а не партийные номера.

Кроме того, чтобы спарсить все парт. номера на странице используйте `browser.find_elements`, который вернет список из всех элементов, соответствующих селектору, в то время как `.find_element` вернет только 1 элемент. Далее вам нужно пройтись циклом по этому списку и из него получить текст каждого элемента.

И ещё вам нужно добавить ожидание загрузки элементов перед `.find_elements` и `.find_element`, иначе Selenium их не найдет, т.к. они ещё не загрузились. Для этого изучите явные и неявные ожидания в Selenium. Это ответ на ваш вопрос, почему может возвращаться пустой список: потому что элементы ещё не загрузились.

С учетом всего этого пример работающего кода:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(
    'https://www.agilent.com/en/product/biopharma-hplc-analysis/aggregate'
    '-fragment-analysis/agilent-bio-sec-5')
# XPATH селектор для парт. номеров:
p_num_xpath = "//tbody//div[contains(@imgurl, 'gc_col_box.jpg')]"
# Ожидание поялвения элементов с парт. номерами:
WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, p_num_xpath)))
part_number_elements = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, p_num_xpath)
part_numbers = []
for element in part_number_elements:
    part_numbers.append(element.text)

# XPATH селектор для кнопки перехода на след стр.:
next_page_btn_xpath = "//li[@class='page-forward']/a"
# Ожидание поялвения кнопки:
WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, next_page_btn_xpath)))
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, next_page_btn_xpath).click()

print(part_numbers)
```